# How to edit a registry value on multiple computers?

Tags: vbscript, registry

I need to edit a registry value on 200+ computers and after several hours of research I still haven't made much progress. I need it to be a .vbs file, and what I came up with is this:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000001
strComputer = "."
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\I placed rest of the path to registry value here"
strValueName = "I placed D-WORD entry name here"
strValue = "http://example.com"
objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue
```

My two main questions are:

1. When I run the script from an admin command prompt, nothing happens. No errors are shown, no change is made to the registry.
2. I understand that for `strComputer` I need to define the computer name. Can I leave this blank if I have many computers I need to run this on?

Comment: The WMI registry methods fail silently, but return a status code. Change the last line into `rc = objRegistry.SetStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strValueName, strValue)` and check the value of `rc` afterwards. Also, what do you mean by "placed D-WORD entry name here"? You can't modify a DWORD value using the `SetStringValue` method. As for your second question: no, you can't leave it blank. If you want to modify the registry on multiple computers you must run `GetObject` in a loop where you iterate over all computers.

Comment: Re: 2, this may not be the best solution but in the past I've done something similar by having the script do a `net view` and parsing the stdout to get the computer name, and then use `reg add` to add the registry data to each computer.